# Trying to fetch 2 checkbox data in one call to create zip file. How should i pass an array in object at one service call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

this is where i am fetching object from backend with single object.

export function downloadFileService(url: string, payload) {

```
    return new Promise(( reject) => {
      const getHeaders: object = { ...PostHeaders, body: JSON.stringify(payload) }
        fetch(url, getHeaders)
      .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
              const getFileNameFromResponse = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition");
                response.blob()
                    .then((response) => {
                        const fileName = getFileNameFromResponse.split('/').pop();
                        const type = 'application/zip';
                        showXLS(response, fileName, type);
                    });
            } else {
                response
                    .json()
                    .then((json) => {
                        const errors = json;
                        reject(errors ? errors.messageList : []);
                    });
            }
        });

    });
}
```

I have created an action for the check box selected, which is just passing one object. I want to pass an array in one object.

```
export const downloadFormPDF = (dispatch, getState) => {

        const state: IAppState = getState(dispatch);

        state.payrollTaxFormReducerState.checked.forEach(item => {
                const taxFormItem=state.payrollTaxFormReducerState.formCardList[item];
                const downloadPdf= 
                    {selectedCards: taxFormItem.itemID + '~' + taxFormItem.federalId + '~' + taxFormItem.formType + '~' + taxFormItem.year + '~' + taxFormItem.quarter};
                    // itemID:taxFormItem.itemID,
                    // federalId: taxFormItem.federalId,
                    // formType: taxFormItem.formType,
                    // year: taxFormItem.year,
                    // quarter: taxFormItem.quarter



                downloadFileService('/mascsr/wfn/payrollTaxForms/metaservices/taxforms/downloadpdf', downloadPdf);
       console.log("download file", downloadPdf, taxFormItem );
     });






}
```

Comment: My gut is telling me that you probably want `Promise.all` which will return an array of promise data from multiple calls but I may have misunderstood exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Right now, the above given code is passing as many checkbox is selected, eachtime it is calling same API. I want pass all the selected object in one object to call service only once.